# how install maven on eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-eclipse-plugin

i want to install maven plug in on eclipse. but when add the maven site in install software section, and beginning to download and install it, an error occurred about dependency. how can fix it?
i want a complete installation guide...

Comment: Here is a video that shows you the common commands and integrating with Eclipse/Spring STS. They have a free 7 day trial on all their videos: http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/maven-fundamentals

Comment: Do we need to install Maven on OS as well. Will installing pluging alone work or not ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

first which dependencies are missing? 
A good maven plugin for eclipse is the eclipse maven sonatype, [m2eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/m2e-downloads.html).

Comment: hi dimitri. thank for answer. i used eclipse marketplace for install and i really install it :)

Answer (score 18):

Do these steps:

1. In Eclipse, go to "Help->Install New Software".
2. Press "Add" in the upper right button in the opened window.
3. Set the name textbox to be "Maven2Eclipse".
4. Set the value textbox to be http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases

   In case the link is not valid, get one from http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/download/
5. Press Ok, select the Maven project, and install it.

Answer (score 6):

> #### Install Maven Plugin for Eclipse
>
> Installing a Maven Plugin for Eclipse can be a bit tricky if you want to get the whole spectrum of features. By default you would go to “Eclipse -> Help -> Software Updates -> Find and Install”, then “Search for new features to install”, then click on “New Remote Site”, and enter the Maven Projects name (e.g. Maven2Plugin) and its home URL there “http://m2eclipse.codehaus.org/“.
>
> Once you install it at first everything would seem quite right. However, if you try “Import” a Maven Project, you will not see such an option in under the “General” menu, since it would be missing.
>
> The reason for that is that “http://m2eclipse.codehaus.org/” brings in an old version of the plugin. (At the moment of writing) It brings in “Maven 2 Plugin 0.0.9″, whereas what you need is 0.0.12.
>
> Hence you read the “Maven Integration for Eclipse” installation guide and point your “New Remote Site” to “http://m2eclipse.codehaus.org/update/” instead of “http://m2eclipse.codehaus.org/“. The one thing to be cautious about is an “update” link will try to also bring “subclipse” and “mylin” projects, hence you will need to “uncheck” them if you do not want to bring them:
>
> [image: maven]

⸺ from https://blog.dotkam.com/2008/02/24/install-maven-plugin-for-eclipse/

Answer (score 5):

> Steps to install maven plugin into eclipse:
>
> In eclipse :
>
> 1. go to Help->install new software.
> 2. Copy this link http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases on "Work With" edit box.
> 3. Select enter and maven link will appear on Name section.
> 4. Select that link and  follow the steps to instal it on eclipse.
>
>    You can find more information regarding different maven builds for eclipse here:
>      http://eclipse.org/m2e/download/

Answer (score 5):

**STEPS TO INSTALL MAVEN (in Eclipse)**:
Maven Eclipse plugin installation step by step:
  1.  Open Eclipse IDE

2. Click Help -> Install New Software...
3. Click Add button at top right corner
4. At pop up: fill up Name as "M2Eclipse" and Location as "http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases"

Now click OK After that installation would be started.

Another way to install Maven plug-in for Eclipse:

```
  1.    Open Eclipse

  2.    Go to Help -> Eclipse Marketplace

  3.    Search by Maven

  4.    Click "Install" button at "Maven Integration for Eclipse" section

  5.    Follow the instruction step by step
```

*After successful installation do the followings in Eclipse:*
1.  Go to Window --> Preferences
2.  Observe, Maven is enlisted at left panel

Comment: I wish more SO answers were like this!